# > 95% disk usage at random moments

Tags: windows, hard-drive

Ever since I connected to internet a few days ago my computer has had random blips where the disk usage will jump to 95% to 100% for a few seconds. I have no idea what’s happening, I tried updating to the most recent version, ending tasks on various applications, and checking drives + disabling superFetch. Some have helped, but never removed the problem. There’s no viruses, I am using windows 10 with a HDD disk, and no background applications. how can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the task manager in advanced view sorted by disk while it is happening?  There are other ways.. but this is the easiest first step and I don't see you mentioning it.  Otherwise, the process monitor and a BUNCH of filters will show you what the drive is actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

Run deep scans of your computer by several reputed antivirus products,
including [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/).

If nothing is found, then you can safely ignore these disk reads,
unless they start happening much more frequently, as
they can be normal disk access by Windows or some installed application.
For example, Windows might be updating its Search Index.

You may try to trace the executable that is doing it via the Task Manager.
You may in the Details pane right-click the headers and add the header
"I/O reads", then click this header to sort it in descending order.
If you don't see anything but legitimate applications, then this might
be normal.